# eligibility for transit visa

Tags: transit-visas

I hold an Egyptian passport and am traveling from Cairo to London via Turkish Airlines. I will have a long layover more than 12 hours.
Do I need a transit visa? or shall I enter Turkey getting a transit visa on arrival at the airport. I have a valid visa to England

Answer (score 0):

A search in [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx) gives the following result:

> **Transit - Turkey (TR)**
>
> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa)**: Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

So you don't need a transit visa. (I am assuming that you will indeed be staying in the international transit area in Istanbul, i. e. both flights are on the same booking.)